# I'm not sure with one is correct....

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

At the class I wrote this at my notebook:
$\frac{a}{d}\equiv\frac{b}{d}\pmod{n}\Leftrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod{n}$

Assume that $d\mid{a}\wedge d\mid{b}\wedge d\mid{n}.$

this is right? or It should be $\frac{a}{d}\equiv\frac{b}{d}\pmod{\frac{n}{d}}\Leftrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod{n}$??

Thank you!!

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541005/congruence-question-with-divisibility

Answer (score 1):

The first is indeed incorrect, the second is correct.

For the second, recall that $a\equiv b \pmod n$ means that (as integers) $a-b=kn$ for some integer $k$. so if $d$ divides $a,b$ and $n$, then you can say $\frac{a}{d}-\frac{b}{d}=k\frac{n}{d}$, so that $\frac{a}{d}\equiv\frac{b}{d} (\bmod\frac{n}{d})$.

By the way, you may have learned by now, or you will later, that if $d|n$, then $d^{-1} \pmod n$ doesn't even exist! That's basically why the first can't be correct. But if you want a counterexample, consider $a=6$, $b=2$, $n=4$ and $d=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your divisibility criteria, i assume youare treating the numbers
as integers, not as residue classes. Then your assumptions give us
 $a=a'd$, $b=b'd$, and $n=n'd$
for some integers $a'$, $b'$, $d'$. Note $a' = a/d$, $b'=b/d$ and $n'=n/d$

Suppose $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$. Then $n'd \mid a'd - b'd$, so $n' \mid a' -b'$. Thus 
$a' \equiv b' \pmod {n'}$.

The converse follows just as easily.

So, yes, you have to change the modulus because you have divided everything by $d$.