# Find integer solutions to linear congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all integer solutions of $2n \equiv 12 \bmod 19$

So I have re-arranged to: $2x-19y=12$ and by the extended Euclidean Algorithm, I get $$x=1 \ $$
$$y=-9$$

However, this is how far I was able to get to and not sure what follow past this point? What exactly are we looking for?

Comment: Have you checked if the values $x=1,y=-9$ are consistent with the problem?

Comment: We can use : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541005/congruence-question-with-divisibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there are infinitely many. Another way to think of $2n \equiv 12 \pmod{19}$ is that $2n - 12 = 19k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $n = \frac{19k + 12}{2}$. Thus any even $k$ will produce an integer solution.

EDIT: It might be better to think in terms of equivalence classes for the sake of negative $k$ values. So maybe $[n] = \bigl[\frac{19k + 12}{2}\bigr]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$. For example: If $k = -2$, then $[n]_{19} = [-13]_{19} = [6]_{19}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since 19 is a prime, there is likely a simpler approach that could be used where you multiply each side of the congruence by the inverse of 2, which in this case is 10.  Now, if you reduce the right hand side by casting out 19s you will get an answer for one route to take.

A quick side note is that 6 appears as a solution as $ 2 * 6 = 12 $.